# Unable to observe Bootstrap event in Aurelia custom attribute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, aurelia

I'm working to incorporate a JavaScript event calendar called [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) into an Aurelia app. I have a standard Aurelia module called `dashboard` and have put the calendar implementation into a separate `.js` file called `calendar.js`, and have created a custom attribute called `calendar`. I'm using a custom attribute because there is no attached `calendar` view, everything is generated in JavaScript.

Since the calendar is not visible when the page loads (because it is not on the main, or active, tab) it is not drawn when the `attached()` method fires in the custom attribute code. I need to be able to observe a Bootstrap event (clicking the tab) from the custom attribute in order to fire a `.render` method to draw the calendar when the tab is eventually clicked.

Here are relevant snippets of my code:

`dashboard.html:`

```
<!-- Standard Bootstrap tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Projects</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="calselect">Calendar</a></li>
                    ...
                    ...
<!-- and further down the same page, the tab panes with their content -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <!-- Table content here... -->
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-white">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div calendar calvisible.bind="calVisible"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- Row -->  
    </div>
</div>
```

`dashboard.js:`

```
...
  constructor(http, dataRepository) {
    this.http = http;
    dataRepository.getProjects().then(projects => this.projects = projects);
    this.calVisible = false;
  };
...
  attached(){
    var cal = document.getElementById('calselect');
      $(cal).on('shown.bs.tab', (e) => {
        this.calVisible = true;
      });
  };
```

`calendar.js:`

```
 @bindable calvisible;
```

Bootstrap fires an event called `'shown.bs.tab'` when a tab is clicked. The correct tab is referenced by `id="calselect"`. When the tab is clicked, the bound property `this.calVisible` is set to true. Subsequently, `calvisible` is bound to the `calendar.js` file.

There are two problems that I can identify. First, from the perspective of `calendar.js`, `calvisible` does not exist until the tab is clicked, causing webpack to complain but not crash the app. I've been unable to catch this using an `if` statement, and I'm not sure why.

Second, when the tab is clicked, even though the value of `calvisible` shows `true` in the `calendar.js` file, it does not trigger a change event that I can observe there, and that is what I need to fire a `.render` method to draw the calendar. I have tried to use `@observable` here, but was not able to get it to work either. What is the correct approach?

Solution -

Here is the winning code based on @Fabio Luz answer below:

```
bind(){
    this.calvisible = this.calvisible;
}

calvisibleChanged(){
    $(this.element).fullCalendar('render');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, I think you should use a custom-element instead of a custom-attribute. To solve the problem of lacking a *view*, Aurelia provides you the `@noView` decorator, [see the docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-custom-elements/7). Your code would look something like this:

```
import {noView} from 'aurelia-framework';

@noView
export class Calendar {
   @bindable calvisible;

   bind() {
     //do your js magic here
   }

   calvisibleChanged() {
   }
}
```

You might still get some js problems. Update your code, see what happens, tell me what's going on and I'll try to help you more.

Comment: Hi @Fabio, that did the trick. I revised the original question to include the working code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, cannot comment. (The answer is same with previous from Fabio Luz's, except a little extra about your typo)

You got a typo in your code ? I see in your `view` you are binding to `calVisible` but it's `calvisible` in `viewModel` If so, do it like this

```
@bindable calVisible; // this was calvisible
```

After this, you can simply do in your viewModel:

```
// Note that this will be called after the value changed
calVisibleChanged(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
        // Do something when cal is shown
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Not a typo. The name in JS file is camelcased, and the one in the template (which is the bound version) is all lowercase.